# Trying to install NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, ethernet

I've just uninstalled Windows 7 from my pc and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop.  Everything has gone well except for one very important thing, namely the network card.

My network card which according to the following command I ran:

```
lspci -vv | grep  "Ethernet"
```

is a **NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)**.  It does work fine under Windows but for some reason I can't get it to work under Ubunutu.  Trying to find drivers to install this card also have proved useless, even though there are countless Windows drivers for this onboard network card.

Is there some generic driver I can install to get this onboard networking card to work?

Comment: The drivers for Nvidia are shockingly poor under Ubuntu.  In the end, I ordered a new non-Nvidia network card for just £4.00 and it was picked up right away.  Sometimes spending a few extra pounds on a decent card is worth less hassle than trying to find the correct driver.