# Ubuntu server on "recycled" Dell LAN throttled to 100mbp/s

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 19.04, lan

I've got Ubuntu server 19.04 on a repurposed 2011 Dell tower.
Back when it was windows, on ETH cabled lan i was at 1Gbp/S but on the Ubuntu now it won't recognize the hardware possibility.

Tried updating firmwares, messed with bios a bit too, the cable and router are both fully capable (modern equipment)

Doing **sudo lshw -C network** returns **nothing**.
Simply running **sudo lshw** returns the full spec list in which, under *-core we can see :

```
     *-bridge
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: MCP61 Ethernet
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 7
      bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
      logical name: enp0s7
      version: a2
      serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      size: 100000000
      capacity: 100000000
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
      capabilities: bridge pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xx latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Running **ifconfig** :

```
enp0s7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet xxx.xxx.xx.xx  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 9468204  bytes 11802225209 (11.8 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 911  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8488610  bytes 6198749826 (6.1 GB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And **ethtool enp0s7**

```
Settings for enp0s7:
Supported ports: [ MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Link detected: yes
```

I know some of you might start with "There is no **1000baseT** so not possible..." but i'm pretty positive the hardware IS gigabit compatible.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Get a new NIC. https://askubuntu.com/questions/383426/trying-to-install-nvidia-corporation-mcp61-ethernet-ubuntu-13-04 ;)

Comment: yes saw that post.. not so much a solution as, more a "replacement", ideally, if the hardware is capable, there should be a software only resolve