# 18.04 Server Can't Get Online After Network Reboot

Tags: networking, server

I have a personal web development server set up in my bedroom and I changed my network's DHCP settings to give the machine a static local IP Address. Everything was okay for a while, and then a god of chaos appeared. I was starting an SSH session onto the server from the comp. in the living room when a cat walked across the power strip that serves the computer and monitor, the lamp, router/modem, and the printer. The power strip is one of those that has a surge protector built in, so of course everything lost power for a few seconds. Server was fine because it's on a different circuit.

Once I restored the power via flipping the switch on the strip, and the router finally finished booting back up, I tried to restart the SSH session, but it failed to connect. Skip a lot of more unnecessary story and here is where I'm at:

The server does connect to the network, as indicated by the activity LED's on the back of the box. The server cannot talk to the network and the network cannot talk to it. "# lshw" shows the Ethernet interface device as being bridge-class and not network. It actually doesn't show any network-class devices.

```
nobody
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: HP Compaq dx2450 Microtower PC (KR612UT#ABA)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: Chassis Version
    serial: MXL85019JL
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=103C_53307F sku=KR612UT#ABA uuid=006E0D58-1216-1310-A14D-9130BC8BB186
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 2A72h
       vendor: OEM_MB
       physical id: 0
       version: 3.02
       serial: MS1C89R60403872
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Phoenix Technologies, LTD
          physical id: 0
          version: 5.19
          date: 11/03/2008
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Sempron(tm) Processor LE-1200
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD Sempron(tm) Processor LE-1200
          slot: Socket AM2
          size: 2100MHz
          capacity: 3700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl cpuid extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch vmmcall cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory:0
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 4
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR2 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: HYMP112U64CP8-S6
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0
             serial: None
             slot: A0
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR2 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: 1G-UDIMM
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: None
             slot: A1
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: None
             vendor: None
             physical id: 2
             serial: None
             slot: A2
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: None
             vendor: None
             physical id: 3
             serial: None
             slot: A3
             width: 64 bits
     *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED
          description: RAM memory
          product: MCP61 Memory Controller
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 6
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: a1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
          capabilities: ht bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
     *-isa
          description: ISA bridge
          product: MCP61 LPC Bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: isa bus_master
          configuration: latency=0
     *-serial
          description: SMBus
          product: MCP61 SMBus
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 1.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm cap_list
          configuration: driver=nForce2_smbus latency=0
          resources: irq:10 ioport:ff00(size=64) ioport:1c00(size=64) ioport:1c40(size=64)
     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
          description: RAM memory
          product: MCP61 Memory Controller
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 1.2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.2
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
          configuration: latency=0
     *-usb:0
          description: USB controller
          product: MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 2
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: a3
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:23 memory:fe02f000-fe02ffff
        *-usbhost
             product: OHCI PCI host controller
             vendor: Linux 4.15.0-66-generic ohci_hcd
             physical id: 1
             bus info: usb@2
             logical name: usb2
             version: 4.15
             capabilities: usb-1.10
             configuration: driver=hub slots=10 speed=12Mbit/s
     *-usb:1
          description: USB controller
          product: MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 2.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
          version: a3
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: debug pm ehci bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:22 memory:fe02e000-fe02e0ff
        *-usbhost
             product: EHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Linux 4.15.0-66-generic ehci_hcd
             physical id: 1
             bus info: usb@1
             logical name: usb1
             version: 4.15
             capabilities: usb-2.00
             configuration: driver=hub slots=10 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usb
                description: Mass storage device
                product: Cruzer Glide
                vendor: SanDisk
                physical id: 6
                bus info: usb@1:6
                logical name: scsi4
                version: 2.01
                serial: 200512339111BA611C6F
                capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-disk
                   description: SCSI Disk
                   product: Cruzer Glide
                   vendor: SanDisk
                   physical id: 0.0.0
                   bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
                   logical name: /dev/sdb
                   version: 2.01
                   serial: 200512339111BA611C6F
                   size: 59GiB (64GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=93f49ea3-3531-429d-a512-39d1addafce7 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                 *-volume:0
                      description: reserved partition
                      vendor: Windows
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
                      logical name: /dev/sdb1
                      serial: 3e37eaab-911e-463d-88a0-f8b954a73b1a
                      capacity: 15MiB
                      capabilities: nofs
                      configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
                 *-volume:1
                      description: Windows NTFS volume
                      vendor: Windows
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,2
                      logical name: /dev/sdb2
                      logical name: /mnt
                      version: 3.1
                      serial: 6658-8c32
                      size: 59GiB
                      capacity: 59GiB
                      capabilities: ntfs initialized
                      configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2019-11-13 22:04:29 filesystem=ntfs label=Flash Drive modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
     *-pci:0
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
          version: a1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pci ht subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
          resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fd700000-fd7fffff memory:fde00000-fdefffff
     *-multimedia
          description: Audio device
          product: MCP61 High Definition Audio
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 5
          bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
          resources: irq:23 memory:fe024000-fe027fff
     *-bridge
          description: Ethernet interface
          product: MCP61 Ethernet
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 7
          bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
          logical name: enp0s7
          version: a2
          serial: 00:22:64:25:cf:14
          capacity: 1000000000
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: bridge pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 latency=0 link=no maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII
          resources: irq:24 memory:fe02d000-fe02dfff ioport:fc00(size=8)
     *-ide:0
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 SATA Controller
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 8
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide pm msi ht pci_native_mode-only_controller__supports_bus_mastering bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=sata_nv latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:20 ioport:9f0(size=8) ioport:bf0(size=4) ioport:970(size=8) ioport:b70(size=4) ioport:f700(size=16) memory:fe02c000-fe02cfff
     *-ide:1
          description: IDE interface
          product: MCP61 SATA Controller
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 8.1
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: ide pm msi ht pci_native_mode-only_controller__supports_bus_mastering bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=sata_nv latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
          resources: irq:21 ioport:9e0(size=8) ioport:be0(size=4) ioport:960(size=8) ioport:b60(size=4) ioport:f200(size=16) memory:fe02b000-fe02bfff
     *-pci:1
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 9
          bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:0 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fdd00000-fddfffff ioport:fdc00000(size=1048576)
     *-pci:2
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: b
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:0 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:fdb00000-fdbfffff ioport:fda00000(size=1048576)
     *-pci:3
          description: PCI bridge
          product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
          version: a2
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:0 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:fd900000-fd9fffff ioport:fd800000(size=1048576)
     *-display
          description: VGA compatible controller
          product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: d
          bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
          version: a2
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
          configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
          resources: irq:22 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:c0000-dffff
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k8temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: a
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD2500AAKX-0
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1H15
             serial: WD-WCC2EP529232
             size: 232GiB (250GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=319aec2e-22a3-406f-894b-c7bc21206b53 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: BIOS Boot partition
                vendor: EFI
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                serial: 65de594a-0d7a-4eb6-9022-aba32dcd45e9
                capacity: 1023KiB
                capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: dfd79953-3e29-4d6e-aff3-bb06fc6b6d82
                size: 232GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2019-08-30 19:04:01 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2019-08-30 19:12:06 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2019-11-21 19:24:47 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: c
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD reader
             product: DVD-ROM TS-H353B
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: bc03
             capabilities: removable audio dvd
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

I would assume at this point that I need to reconfigure the device as network-class, but I don't know where to begin with that.

Comment: You should have taught your cat, 'Not to play with computer cables'. And at the same importance, give your cat something that she can play and bite for real fun.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Lol, she has plenty she can play with. But in the moment, she wanted to be there, and I was physically unable to put myself where she was to stop her.

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect and reconnect the network cable of the server or reboot it after the power failure of the network? It just might be using its old IP address while the network expects another. Related: [Trying to install NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383426/trying-to-install-nvidia-corporation-mcp61-ethernet-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: @Melebius The network was set to give it a static IP address. I deleted the setting in dhcp, I’ve swapped what physical port on the network the machine was on, rebooted the network and the server, factory reset the network, etc.  The problem was netplan? It was configured to use the onboard network card, but instead it set it up as a bridge device instead of networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took more guessing around and suggestions from a web forum, but I managed to bring it online again. The on-board network adapter is still listed as a bridge device and still disabled. I found an Ethernet <-> USB adapter I had purchased at a literal junk store. I plugged it in and turned the machine on and it recognized the adapter, but didn't enable it itself. So then I took a guess at configuring netplan to use it (didn't know what to use for the device name). It didn't work, so I rebooted just in case. Boot screen (had to open the boot log after because it was too fast) gave me a new thing to plop into the netplan config. I tried it and it worked instantly.